# Is there a simple way to retrofit an existing toilet with a top-mounted sink?

Tags: toilet, sink

I'm looking for a toilet with an integrated sink.  I've seen them on rare occasions: flushing the toilet activates the sink, which re-fills the toilet and tank using the water that drains through the integrated sink above the tank.

Is there a simple way to retrofit an existing toilet with a top-mounted sink?

If retrofitting one is not an option, is there a name for this that I can search for?

Comment: I think it is a good question.  How is this different from this question -http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/30926/what-types-of-electrical-outlets-are-found-in-a-typical-home-in-the-usa ??  He just wants to know if this option exists.

Comment: "Is there a simple way to retrofit an existing toilet with a top-mounted sink?" - Is a DIY question. If you cannot buy a product to meet your needs, you make it. Thats DIY. I've posted an edit to shift the question to fit in these guidelines.

Comment: Removing my -1 with the latest edits and reopening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like [this](http://www.eco-buildingproducts.com/products-page/kitchen-and-bathroom/sinkpositive-toilet-lid-sink/?gclid=CK7a15b6kbkCFYai4Aod8mAAsQ)?  If you google "grey water toilet sink" you will get lots of results.

Comment: "prison toilet" could also turn up a few hits. Some are grey-water based. Their main feature is compact size and a single sink/toilet unit.